# Why does this Parsec parser enter an infinite loop?

Tags: haskell, parsec

The following parser enters an infinite loop for any input.

```
data Ast
    = Number Int
    | Identifier String
    | Operation Ast BinOp Ast
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data BinOp = Plus | Minus
    deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)

number = Number <$> read <$> many1 digit

identifier = Identifier <$> many1 letter

operator = choice $ mkParser <$> [(Plus, '+'), (Minus, '-')]
  where mkParser (f, c) = f <$ char c

operation = Operation <$> ast <*> operator <*> ast

ast :: Parser Ast
ast = operation <|> number <|> identifier
```

The problem is somewhere in the operation parser. I assume it's related to the alternate parsing but I don't understand it.

Can you explain what the problem is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is really in infinite recursion. Your `ast` parser calls `operation` parser first. But then `operation` parser calls `ast` back again. And so on. `<*>` operator for parsing also runs parsers. Explanation of difference from `<|>` in very informal manner: `<*>` runs parsers in sequence one by one whether `<|>` runs first parser and only if it fails runs second.

```
operation = Operation <$> ast <*> operator <*> ast
ast       = operation <|> number <|> identifier
```

Basically, even with rearranging parsers your approach won't work. See this answer on similar question for explanation: [Megaparsec: Not able to parse arithmetic string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294378/megaparsec-not-able-to-parse-arithmeitc-string/43299434#43299434)

Comment: From my understanding, it seems it isn't possible because "Parsec can't handle left-recursive grammars" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43299434/1663462).

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski you're correct. But it's possible to change your grammar in a such way that it's still equivalent to its left-recursive version but doesn't contain left recursion.